# Edit Text to long variable issue?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a timer app, I have an EditText for taking an input number and based on my radio button selected, multiply the input to be equal to long millisInFuture for the CountDownTimer class. but apparently there is something wrong with parsing my EditText as a long. here is the part for RadioGroup:

```
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (checkedId == rdSeconds.getId()) {
                et_num.setHint("Seconds");
                String value = et_num.getText().toString();
                //selectedOption is a long variable
                selectedOption = Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
            } else {
                et_num.setHint("Minutes");
                String value = et_num.getText().toString(); 
                selectedOption = Long.parseLong(value) * 60000; //line 102
            }


        }
    });
```

Here is part of the error it gaves me?

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:455)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:485)
    at com.example.timemachine.MainActivity$2.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:102)
```

Comment: Message is clear `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`, an empty string cannot be parsed as a number.

Comment: Can you please share your xml?

Comment: Abdul Waheed, What sasikumar answered is right. But to answer your second question, as to why that is empty, by default, as soon as the UI is loaded, the first radio button will be in the selected state. This triggers the OnCheckedChangeListener method. At this time, your edittext is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your editText have proper value before parse long

```
            String value = et_num.getText().toString();

             if(value != null && !value.isEmpty())
             { 
             selectedOption = Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
             }
```

Comment: this will not solve the problem. this needs to find out why that is empty?

Comment: because you may not have any text in et_num

Answer (score 1):

The error is very clear that you parse empty String to type Number. There some way to handle this

1. You can check the value on your Edit Text as @sasikumar answer like :

   ```
   if (!yourEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      /* Then parse your value from Edit Text to Number */
   }
   ```
2. You can use NumberFormatException :

   ```
    try {
      /* Then parse your value from Edit Text to Number */
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      /* Any error about formating will catch here */
    }
   ```